# Textarea data submit and display -Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

What's the code to create a textarea and submit button in Wordpress?
When I enter text into textarea and click the submit button I want it to display text underneath textarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will create a textarea with a submit button, which will display a paragraph beneath, containing whatever is typed into the text area. You can add this into whatever wordpress template file you like.

```
<form method="post">
<textarea name="text1"></textarea>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['text1'] ) ) {?>
   <p><?=$_POST['text1']?></p>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, when I press the submit button it didn't show the text. I copied the code into a Wordpress html box.

Comment: This code needs to go into a php file as it is written in PHP. Your wordpress site is made up of a number of .php files such as header.php, index.php and footer.php. [This article](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/wordpress/how-to-add-php-code-to-wordpress-post-or-page) explains how you can add the code using a plugin if you don't feel comfortable editing the php files directly.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. You are great.